# How do I calculate effect size in a pretest-posttest three group randomized study for two planned contrasts (ANCOVA)?

Tags: spss, experiment-design, effect-size, ancova, contrasts

I am having a hard time calculating the individual effect sizes for ANCOVA simple contrasts ($1$ vs. $2$ and $1$ vs. $3$) in a randomized pretest-posttest design study with three groups. In the ANCOVA, I used posttest score as an independent variable, condition as a factor, and pretest score as a covariate. I ran the analysis in SPSS, and the output provides me with the adjusted posttest means, the adjusted posttest mean differences, and the SE for both contrasts. What can I do?

Comment: Greetings and welcome to CV! Which effect sizes are you looking for?